# add a tab to facebook page programmatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion

I have a site that hosts music (stereokiller.com) - a sample band page would be http://www.stereokiller.com/rapture .

I am attempting to create a facebook application that will insert a new tab into a user's band page on facebook loaded with the player and some other information from my site. However, i'm not sure how to pass the iframe app any parameters to determine which band information to show? I'm aware of the FB_SIG_PAGE_ID which I could then get the owner page name from the Graph API, but if there are multiple bands on my site with the same name then we could have issues.

---

[solved]
I figured it out.

do an http call to graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token={access token}. loop through results with the access token retrieved through the prior call, then do http post to graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}/tabs with the form param {app_id} for the app of which you want to add.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a very similar issue but having a hard time following your solution. How were you able to pass the unique params to the iframe so that it points to the correct band's page? Thanks!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can install a profile_tab at the end of the current list of installed tabs for a page by issuing an HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/tabs with a Page Access Token:

Parameter   Description                                             Type    Required
app_id          ID of the application for which to install the tab.     string  Y

If the create is successful, you get the following return:
Description                 Type
If the create succeeded     boolean