# How can I add a custom tab to my Facebook pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to add a custom tab to my Facebook page, without the use of static iframes? I have followed the documentation of Facebook regarding the installing of tabs but couldn't find the solutions for my problem.

I have fetched the pages of my users using the `manage_permissions` but am unable to get the custom tab install to a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to:

http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=YOUR_APP_ID&pages, you should get a select with all the pages where you are an administrator, so you can install that app's tab to any of them.

You need to have an application created (https://developers.facebook.com/) and properly configured.

You should have the app's Page Tab section configured also.

Another way of installing the tab to a page is going to your app's profile page (http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=YOUR_APP_ID) and click on Add to My Page.

Comment: I have created an app nd used that method in creating the tab by  configuring but i need to add a custom tab to a particular page by using php code ...
`http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=YOUR_APP_ID&pages`
when i click and use the above link, it is redirecting to my facebook homepage....how to use this code in php..?

Comment: you can't add a tab to a page programmatically, "http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=YOUR_APP_ID&pages" is as close as it gets.

Comment: even better, if you have the page id:

http://facebook.com/add.php?pi_key=YOUR_APP_KEY&pages=1&page=YOUR_PAGE_ID

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162071/add-a-tab-to-facebook-page-programatically, maybe that HTTP-POST-to-the-graph thing could work